# Como revisar respostas incorretas mas "de boa qualidade"?

Tags: debate, respostas, filas-de-análise

Na fila de revisão "Publicações de baixa qualidade" apareceu [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-centralizar-verticalmente-o-conteudo-de-um-elemento/142#142) que, coincidentemente, eu próprio já havia comentado a respeito da sua incorreção. Entretanto, apesar dos seus 3 votos contrários e da *engine* do SO tê-la identificado como de baixa qualidade (pelo seu conteúdo mínimo), eu ainda a considero uma resposta válida (no sentido de que é uma tentativa genuína de se responder à pergunta) - somente sucinta.

O que eu devo fazer? Marcar "Parece boa" me soa um pouco incoerente, depois que eu próprio deixei um comentário apontando uma falha... Editar está fora de questão, pois o objetivo da revisão não é mexer no conteúdo. E "Recomendar Exclusão", sei lá, não me parece correto: ainda que isso beneficiaria o autor (pois ele ganha a reputação perdida de volta) e talvez a comunidade (uma resposta errada a menos), como já disse é uma resposta honesta e sem nenhum problema que justifique uma ação externa, na minha opinião a decisão de removê-la/alterá-la/deixar como está deveria ser do autor (mesmo porque [não é esse o caso mas] a remoção de posts pode levar um usuário a [ter sua conta bloqueada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/177950)).

Nesse caso específico vou apenas "Pular", mas gostaria de saber no geral: respostas incorretas devem ser recomendadas para remoção, ainda que não exista nenhum outro problema com elas?

Comment: Tenho minha posição mas prefiro ouvir a comunidade. O caminho é +/- esse mesmo. Não devemos nos  preocupar com a reputação de ninguém aí, ajudar o conteúdo do site é o objetivo. A remoção por terceiros deveria ser algo raro mas podemos ter outra postura também e ser mais ativo na moderação comunitária do conteúdo. Criarei uma resposta se não tiver nada que eu goste mais tarde.

Comment: @bigown Só esclarecendo: não estou levando em conta a reputação do autor na decisão, apenas citando o fato de que ele se beneficiaria da ação. De fato, sempre procurei deixar bem claro pros novos usuários que votos contrários, fechamentos e remoções não são "punições", mas sim maneiras de manter o site organizado e seu conteúdo relevante.

Comment: Exato, eu entendi, reforcei para quem está aprendendo.